# \longtable caption showing and disappearing -- how to make it appear?

Tags: longtable, landscape

I have been trying to use `\longtable` within `landscape` environment. Finally I got it, the table looks fine in a temporary file, but when I compile the main document, the caption disappears. I've just copied the preamble from the main document to the tmp file -- the temporary compiles just fine, while the main without the caption (although the label for table works).

Here is the tmp file:

```
% !TEX options=--shell-escape
\pdfoutput=1
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfinfo
{
    /Author ()
    /Title ()
    /Subject ()
    /Keywords ()
}
\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,12pt]{mwrep}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{algolrevived}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{icomma}  % for comma as decimal separator
\usepackage{lmodern} % different looks (font-times), and (!!!) polish characters
\selectlanguage{polish}


\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
% packages required by `pandoc' generated file:
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}

\usepackage{graphicx} % figures (?)
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}  % <- tikz
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tabela}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%conditional compilation:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{PUREFINAL}
\togglefalse{PUREFINAL}
\newtoggle{paper}
\togglefalse{paper}
% \toggletrue{paper}

\newif\ifswitchFinal
\iftoggle{paper}{ % \tDpi def.: target dpi, tDpi
  \newcommand{\tDpi}{600}
}{
  \newcommand{\tDpi}{72}
}
\iftoggle{PUREFINAL}{
  \switchFinaltrue
  }{
  \switchFinalfalse
}

\usepackage{python}
\patchcmd{\endpython}{python }{python3 }{}{}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}  % another package for listings, with colors

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}  % centering column
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\addto\captionspolish{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Dodatki}
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Dodatek}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Dodatki}
}

\renewcommand*\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}  % figures numbering
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}  % 2019.09.17

\newcommand{\arctg}{\operatorname{arctg}}

\hyphenpenalty=10000        % nie dziel wyrazów zbyt często
\clubpenalty=10000          % kara za sierotki
\widowpenalty=10000         % nie pozostawiaj wdów
\brokenpenalty=10000        % nie dziel wyrazów między stronami
\exhyphenpenalty=999999     % nie dziel słów z myślnikiem
\righthyphenmin=3           % dziel minimum 3 litery

\tolerance=4500
\pretolerance=250
\hfuzz=1.5pt
\hbadness=1450

\sloppy                     % umacnia pozycję prawego marginesu

\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-5cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\topmargin -1.25cm
\footskip 1.4cm

\linespread{1.3}  % For use 1.6, for one-and-a-half spacing 1.3.

%relative path to images:
\graphicspath {{../../../../img/}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Dodatek 2: Opis konstrukcji wykorzystanego modelu geometrycznego}

Testy poprawności teorii diagramów drogi słońca i kąta padania promieni słonecznych,
opisanej w niniejszej rozprawie, przeprowadzono z wykorzystaniem falsyfikacji [...]

Protokół konstrukcji wygenerowany przez aplikację zamieszczono
w tab. \ref{tab:constructionProtocol}. \\

\input{ConstructionProtocol.tex}

\section*{Opis modelu}

Model geometryczny został stworzony według następujących głównych założeń: [...]

\end{document}
```

and a fragment of the `ConstructionProtocol.tex`:

```
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.03}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.15}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.30}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.30}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.20}}@{}}
\caption{Protokół konstrukcji modelu geometrycznego do przykładu 3.3 z \cite{PTFKES2006}.} \label{tab:constructionProtocol} \\
\toprule
% \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Number} & Theory & Question & Explanation  \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Nr} & Nazwa & Opis & Wartość & Definicja \\
\midrule
\endhead

1 & Funkcja B & ~ & B(n) = (n - 1) * 360 / 365 & ~ \\
2 & Funkcja E & Jeżeli(0 $\leq$ n $\leq$ 365, 229.2 (0 + 0cos((B(n))°) -
0.03sin((B(n))°) - 0.01cos(2(B(n))°) - 0.04sin(2(B(n))°))) & E(n) = If(0
$\leq$ n $\leq$ 365, 229.2 (0 + 0cos(((n - 1) * 360 / 365)°) - 0.03sin(((n - 1) *
360 / 365)°) - 0.01cos(2((n - 1) * 360 / 365)°) - 0.04sin(2((n - 1) *
360 / 365)°))) & Jeżeli(0 $\leq$ n $\leq$ 365, 229.2 (0 + 0cos((B(n))°) -
0.03sin((B(n))°) - 0.01cos(2(B(n))°) - 0.04sin(2(B(n))°))) \\
3 & Funkcja Fix & ~ & Fix(n) = Jeżeli(n \textgreater{} 0, floor(n),
ceil(n)) & ~ \\
4 & Funkcja dec & ~ & dec(dn) = Jeżeli(1 $\leq$ dn $\leq$ 366, 23.45sin(360((dn +
284) / 365)°)) & ~ \\
[...]
136 & Liczba prec & ~ & prec = 0 & ~ \\
137 & Liczba scs\textsubscript{loc} & round((mns\textsubscript{loc} -
Fix(mns\textsubscript{loc})) * 60, prec) & scs\textsubscript{loc} = 0 &
round((mns\textsubscript{loc} - Fix(mns\textsubscript{loc})) * 60,
prec) \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

The pages with and without the caption (first the tmp file, second the main/final):

[image: longtable with caption, tmp file]

[image: longtable with missing caption, the main file]

P.S.
The table was generated with pandoc, from html file Geogebra construction protocol. I am struggling with the table for several days, after many attempts decided to post the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: In the table code, you need to have an `\endhead` section, and also an `\endfirsthead`  section.

Comment: `\endhead` was present in the original example. The addition of `\endfirsthead` did not help. I did included a caption for the first head and after, but in the example file every caption was present and in the main, final file all of them are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the cause of the problem and the solution.

The whole document consists of a few files, included in the main `.tex`, while the temporary file included just the table (through `\input` command). The main file input appendices `.tex`, which imported the table. It seems it was one `\input` too much. When I copied and pasted the contents of the table, directly into the appendices file, it compiled as it was supposed to.

[image: The first page with the longtable, along with the caption]

and the second page:

[image: The second page, with caption, referencing the table.]

Comment: You can accept ow answer. Off topic: I would edit your table code and complete math expression insert in math node ter use `\cos` instead of `cos` etc.